# T-SQL query to show table definition of sys.time_zone_info

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, system-tables

Following query could be used to show definitions of custom table.

```
SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
       , IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PostHistory'
```

not work for sys tables

```
SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
       , IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'sys.time_zone_info'
```

I guess the info is in another table in another database what are they?

I've also tried `sp_help 'sys.time_zone_info'`, and got

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_help', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`sys.time_zone_info`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-time-zone-info-transact-sql) is a system view with the definition:

```
CREATE VIEW sys.time_zone_info AS
    SELECT  name,
            current_utc_offset,
            is_currently_dst
    FROM OPENROWSET(TABLE TIME_ZONE_INFO, SYSUTCDATETIME())
```

The `OPENROWSET` call is a wrapper over an internal structure. You cannot get information about it directly.

The columns returned by the view are shown in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-time-zone-info-transact-sql)

```
+--------------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    Column name     |  Data type   |                                                          Description                                                           |
+--------------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| name               | sysname      | Name of the time zone in Windows standard format. For example, Cen. Australia Standard Time or Central European Standard Time. |
| current_utc_offset | nvarchar(12) | Current offset to UTC. For example, +01:00 or -07:00.                                                                          |
| is_currently_dst   | bit          | True if currently observing daylight savings time.                                                                             |
+--------------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and from [nchar and nvarchar (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql#remarks):

> **sysname** is a system-supplied user-defined data type that is functionally equivalent to **nvarchar(128)**, except that it is not nullable. **sysname** is used to reference database object names.

You can also obtain the information you want from the system catalogue views, for example:

```
SELECT
    AC.column_id,
    AC.[name],
    data_type = T.[name],
    AC.max_length,
    AC.[precision],
    AC.scale,
    AC.collation_name,
    AC.is_nullable
FROM sys.all_objects AS AO
JOIN sys.all_columns AS AC
    ON AC.[object_id] = AO.[object_id]
JOIN sys.types AS T
    ON T.user_type_id = AC.user_type_id
WHERE
    AO.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'sys.time_zone_info');
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9e7348fd2a132594be5dca287bd2ce23)